# Validate a WYSIWYG for empty whitespaces

Tags: javascript, regex, wysiwyg

I am trying to validate a WYSIWYG editor using regular expression, when it has empty whitespaces (enter key, spaces), it will return me true.

The example outcome of a mixed spaces and enter key is:

```
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    ... 
(not that the line number of <p> tag is not fixed, it depends on how many enter key i press)
```

Note:

1. Sometime there are spaces between the `&nbsp;` tag, sometime not.
2. Number of `<p>` tags is not fixed, it depends on how many enter key i press.

I need to come out a regex of the mentioned criteria, but i facing difficulties where

1. The on-and-off spaces between `&nbsp;` tag
2. 1 or more group of `<p>` tag that has `&nbsp;`

The regex i tried on my own:

`/^<p>(&nbsp;)+(\t)*<\/p>$`

My code snippet test result for separated `<p>` tags:

`<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;</p>`   -> not matched

`<p>&nbsp;</p>`     -> matched

`<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;</p>`   -> not matched

`<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>`   -> matched

Comment: So your provided code snippet will validate as `false` or `true`?

Comment: Try `/^<p>(?:&nbsp;|[^\S\r\n])*<\/p>$/gm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you want something like this.
It is much more easier to understand a `replaceAll` regex rather than adding a more complex one.
Just execute the following example to see it in action.

```js
//Replace all prototype function
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
  var target = this;
  return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};

//A function to detect if the content is empty
function isContentEmpty(text) {

  text = text.replaceAll("&nbsp;", "").
  replaceAll(" ", "").
  replaceAll("<p>", "").
  replaceAll("</p>", "").trim();

  return (text.length == 0) ? true : false;

}

//Empty test
var emptyText = document.getElementById("empty").innerHTML;
console.log("Is [id = empty] content is empty: ", isContentEmpty(emptyText));

//Not empty test
var notEmptyText = document.getElementById("not-empty").innerHTML;
console.log("Is [id = not-empty] content is empty: ", isContentEmpty(notEmptyText));
```

```html
<div id="empty">
  <p>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp; &nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</div>



<div id="not-empty">
  <p>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp; content &nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```